# mypy arg-type avoidance using decorator

Tags: python, mypy

I have a class, which defines an optional attribute

```
class Stuff:
    config: Optional[Dict] = None

    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

At some point in my code I have a function that takes the config attribute as an input.

```
def method(config: Dict):
    """docstring"""
    print(type(config))
    print(config)
```

The config argument now has to be a Dict. One way to solve this is to check prior to calling `method` like

```
stuff = Stuff()
if not isinstance(stuff.config, dict):
    raise Exception("config needs to be a dict")
method(stuff.config)
```

This is OK by mypy. Now, suppose I would rather check this using a decorator;

```
def decorator(func: Callable) -> Any:
    def wrapper(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
        if not args[0]:
            raise Exception("config may not be None")
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper

@decorator
def method(config: Dict):
...
```

Calling this would then be reduced to

```
stuff = Stuff()
method(stuff.config)
```

This works as intended in runtime, but using the decorator solution yields a mypy error: `Argument 1 to "method" has incompatible type "Optional[Dict[Any, Any]]"; expected "Dict[Any, Any]"  [arg-type]`

How can I adjust the decorator solution to work with mypy?

Edit; corrected the call to `method`.

Comment: Your function doesn't take the attribute as an argument. It takes a `dict`, which could be *supplied* by the class attribute, but clearly not if the class attribute doesn't have a `dict` as its value. The decorator doesn't work because `mypy` will only simulate code so far in order to perform type narrowing. Crossing multiple lexical boundaries to do so is just too far.

Comment: In the non-decorator solution, raising an exception prior to calling `method` satisfies mypy. I presume this is because it can be statically deduced that the call will not be made if the argument is `None`. Hence, the argument type in `method` becomes simply `Dict`.

Comment: Basically, you are *changing* the signature of `method` at runtime: you said *statically* that it must take a `dict`, but the function bound to it after the decorator is applied will actually accept an `Optional[dict]`. This is *quite* different from saying that what is passed to `method` is actually a `dict`, even though the static type of `stuff.config` is `Optional[dict]`.

Comment: Yes, it's the *lexical* proximity of the `if` segment to the method call that lets `mypy` perform type narrowing on the static type of `stuff.config`. Wrapping that in  a pair of (vaguely-typed) functions removes the necessary proximity to perform the type narrowing.

Comment: Even in your decorator, there's no static type information that appears to make the `if` statement necessary. `args[0]` could be a value of *any* type, and there's no static information about what argument `func` requires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I adjust the decorator solution to work with mypy?

You can't.

You specified the type is Foo, so subsequent
attempts to supply Optional[Foo] won't lint cleanly.

Mypy currently does some remarkable lexical analysis
and theorem proving, but it doesn't delve far enough
into the code to agree with your perspective
on "*this* argument supplied is *good enough*".
One could propose a feature, and merge a pull request,
but that's out-of-scope for this SO question.

---

Consider defining a new `class MyDict:`
which makes things easy on static analysis,
and which does the app-specific runtime
checking / enforcement that you require.

Comment: You can, but it requires a little bit of work in hinting the decorator.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this much more specific decorator, with useful type hints:

```
def decorator(func: Callable[[dict], None]) -> Callable[[Optional[dict]], None]:
    def wrapper(d: Optional[dict]) -> None:
        if d is None:
            raise Exception("config may not be None")
        return func(d)

    return wrapper
```

Now, you *can* decorate `method` and change its static type, because `mypy` can see from the type hints on `decorator` alone that it changes the static type of `method`.

```
@decorator
def method(config: dict):
    ...


# No errors, even though method originally could not accept an argument
# of None
stuff = Stuff()
method(stuff.config)
```

The decorator *explicitly* turns a function of type `Callable[[dict], None]` into a function of type `Callable[[Optional[dict]],  None]` that behaves the way you want.

So the problem with your decorator is that *it* does not provide the static typing necessary for `mypy` to understand what it will do to `method`.

Can we generalize the static typing in the decorator to allow it to be applied to more functions? Consider what we need, given what it does:

1. `func` should have type `Callable[[T, ...], RV]`. The only thing we want to say for certain is that its first argument is type `T`. The other arguments and the return type are arbitrary.
2. `wrapper`'s first argument should be of type `Optional[T]`, and we'll use type narrowing in the body to "reduce" the value to a value of type `T` before passing it to `func`.
3. `wrapper` should return a value of the same type as the original caller. (That's the best we can do; we can't say it will return *exactly* the same value `func` returns.)

So let's give it a try:

```
$ cat tmp.py
from typing import Optional, Callable, TypeVar, ParamSpec, Concatenate


T = TypeVar('T')
RV = TypeVar('RV')
P = ParamSpec('P')

def decorator(func: Callable[Concatenate[T, P], RV]) -> Callable[Concatenate[Optional[T], P], RV]:
    def wrapper(x: Optional[T], *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> RV:
        if x is None:
            raise Exception("first argument may not be None")
        return func(x, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


class Stuff:
    config: Optional[dict] = None

    def __init__(self):
        pass


@decorator
def method(config: dict):
    ...

stuff = Stuff()
method(stuff.config)

$ mypy tmp.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Note the use of `ParamSpec` to *capture* the types of whatever arguments are passed to `func`, so that we can provide the same types to the wrapper. (And that this requires Python 3.10 or later, or the `typing-extensions` package.)